# display a site admin template django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have website template and i want to show it on my django app.
I created a project with an app and stored the template in templates directory according to http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html

Then I created a view to display that template. On running the it only shows the html but no css or javascript in webpage. When i open same index.html in browser it is displayed correctly.[image]

My code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'orders/index.html')
```

[image]

It should look like this::

[image]

Comment: don't put your CSS, IMG and JS in the template folder, but in your static folder (as defined in your settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up a static directory in which you want to store all your static files (img, css, js).

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

*Pay attention, in that case your static folder will be in a project folder it's suitable for development but not good for production.*

Copy all static files in the created directory, better in a respective folder. For example, a path to style.css might be mysite.com/static/css/style.css

Now you can link it in your base.html or whatever:

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```